# Trouble deploying an ERC20 contract remix

Tags: remix, erc-20, testnets, smart-contract-wallets, remix-tests

Hi so some assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am able to successfully deploy my contract when my ether is set to 0. It will go through MM and everything looks solid. By the way I am using test ether with the ropsten network. However when I deploy my contract with 1-5 ether it gives me an error, gas estimation failed: Do you want to force sending? Execution reverted, which always ends up failing. Any reason for why 0 ether will succeed, and then any amount over 0 ether my txn fails?

Comment: Is the constructor is payable ?

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?